# Apache Camel: Getting the aggregator's response?

Tags: apache-camel, aggregator

We use a splitter to iterate through the files within a zipped file, and along, we use a custom aggregator as well that gives us a list of bodies - of both the files within that main zipped file. Now, after that split, I'd like to extract the headers set during the aggregation block- processing which happens on the aggregator's result. But, the aggregator's output seems to get lost, and I don't get anything back after the split block.

I'm sure I'm not getting the basics of this. Would appreciate it if someone could help here.

```
<route id="main-route">
        <split streaming="true">
            <ref>zipSplitter</ref>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <method bean="fileHandler" method="isY" />
                    <to uri="direct:y" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="direct:x" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <to uri="direct:aggregate" />
       </split>
       <!--Do something by extracting the headers set during the processing underneath in the aggregation block i.e. process-data -->
</route>
<route id="aggregate-data">
        <from uri="direct:aggregate" />
        <camel:aggregate strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" completionSize="2">
            <camel:correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </camel:correlationExpression>
            <to uri="direct:process-data"/>
        </camel:aggregate>
 </route>
```

Aggregator-

```
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
    Map<String, Object> newHeaders = newExchange.getIn().getHeaders();

    ArrayList<Object> list = null;
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(newBody);
        newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
        return newExchange;
    } else {
        Map<String, Object> olderHeaders = oldExchange.getIn().getHeaders();
        olderHeaders.putAll(newHeaders);
        list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);

        list.add(newBody);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep the aggregate logic inside the split scope. There should be single aggregate instance doing aggregation for your split as below,

```
     <route id="main-route">
        <split streaming="true" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy">
            <ref>zipSplitter</ref>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <method bean="fileHandler" method="isY" />
                    <to uri="direct:y" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="direct:x" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>               
       </split>
  </route>
```

you have to specify your aggregation strategy in split tag as a attribute like above code. So that, exchange return by every iteration will be available in aggregation strategy bean to aggregate.

Hope it helps :)